# SpriteKit (Obj-C) RemoveFromParent Isn't Working

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, parent, removechild, skaction

Here's my code:

```
if (descriptionWindow.alpha != 0.0) {
            // It's on. Turn it off.
            NSLog(@"Turned off.");
            [descriptionWindow runAction:[SKAction removeFromParent] completion:^{
                NSLog(@"Removed.");
            }];
        } else {
            // It's off. Turn it on.
            NSLog(@"Turned on.");
            [descriptionWindow runAction:[SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0.5]];
            [self fadeOutAllNodesExcept:descriptionWindow withDuration:0.5];
        }
```

My problem is that the "Removed." `NSLog()` never gets called, and the `-removeFromParent` doesn't work, either. So, I tried putting in a breakpoint. The code runs up to that line OK, but it never removes it from the scene. The "Turned off." `NSLog()` gets called each time the if-statement is run, but the code right after it doesn't. I've tried multiple things. Is there some bug that makes this happen, or am I doing something wrong?

***EDIT***

**If it helps or changes anything, I tried similar code with the `descriptionWindow`. I tried fading it out, too, but the node doesn't seem to be responding to anything.**

Comment: Could you share additional info about descriptionWindow?

Comment: The description window is merely an SKSpriteNode, and it's not nil. All I'm trying to do is fade it in when the user touches a certain button (which is where this code above is run), and then fade it out whenever the user touches the screen again.